# Issue in aggregations in elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using ELK version 6.1.1 with in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

problem statement:

I have logs which are getting logged in every hour. First I want to find max of a particular field coming in that log line, now I want to get that log line whose field's value is max and extract value of another field from that logline and show on matrix visualization.

I am able to get the max of that field but i don't know how can we get that logline and extract another field from that.

It is just like a db query -

> SELECT field2 FROM loggs WHERE field1 = 'max(field1)' AND duration =
>   'selected_duration'

;

Can anyone help me out to get the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
GET loggs/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAMEField":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    },
    "max_score": {
      "max": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
      }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-4d/d",
        "lte": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to give this idea, So currently with this I am getting two different values say value of field1 and value of field2 both. Now I want to find the value of field2 if max of field one found in same log-line.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be :

```
GET  metricbeat-*/_search
  {
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-15m",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
        "allField2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "field2"
        }
      },
        "maxValue": {
           "max": {
             "field": "field1"
                }
        }

    }
}
```

And the Output will be :

```
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 65,
    "successful": 65,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1215,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "allField2": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 80,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 0.21092499792575836,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.21797500550746918,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.22032499313354492,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.23864999413490295,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.23907500505447388,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.24650000035762787,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.24842500686645508,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.2488500028848648,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.2504250109195709,
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": 0.2511749863624573,
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "maxValue": {
      "value": 3.1563000679016113
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
GET loggs/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "max": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-4d/d",
        "lte": "now/d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Angel, The script that you have given is giving only max of field but I want to get the value of another field say field2 of the log line whose field1's value is maximum in a given duration.